# as3 URL request - retry url request

Tags: actionscript-3, urlrequest

I'm creating retry mechanism for URL request.
I would like to send the request again if i didn't get ant answer after 10 seconds.
The problem is how to deal with respone for the previous request in case it recieved after more than 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `URLLoader` in order to send http requests. The loader has a `close` method. It's important to put it in try-catch, and also it's good to remove the listeners. This way even if there is a response with a delay, you won't get it. But best is to call `close` AND remove listeners :)